# Oracle 12c - how to partition existing table?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, partitioning

Is it possible to partition existing table in Oracle without creating secondary table?

Or is recommended to create a second table first with all partitions and then copy over everything from a first table?

I have table 't1':

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    accountnumber VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    yr_qtr INT NOT NULL
)
```

yr_qtr has 15 distinct values.

I want to partition table 't1' based on yr_qtr which is int (or create 't2' with yr_qtr partitions).

Comment: Can you try this: 
`ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY
      PARTITION BY RANGE (yr_qtr) INTERVAL (1)
      ( PARTITION P1 VALUES LESS THAN (2) /*add as per requirement (15 as you said) */
       ) ONLINE;`

Comment: Also yr_qtr number will keep growing over time. So need probably some sort of 'Automatic' partition. Currently these are values for yr_qtr: 20141, 20142, 20143, 20144, 20141, 20152, 20153, 20154, 20161, 20162, 20163, 20164, 20171, 20172, 20173. Expecting to have more in the future: 20174, 20181, 20182...

Comment: Already included *INTERVAL PARTITION*. Also do take care of the indexes if any.

Comment: Tried above query: `ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY 
PARTITION BY RANGE (yr_qtr) 
INTERVAL (1) 
( PARTITION P1 VALUES LESS THAN (2) )
ONLINE;`

Error: `ORA-14006: invalid partition name
14006. 00000 -  "invalid partition name"
*Cause:    a partition name of the form <identifier> is
           expected but not present.
*Action:   enter an appropriate partition name.`

Comment: Ran fine for me @(Oracle Live SQL)

Answer (score 1):

```
drop table t1;


CREATE TABLE t1 (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    accountnumber VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL,
    yr_qtr INT NOT NULL
);

insert all 
into t1 values(1,'AB',20141)
into t1 values(2,'CD',20142)
into t1 values(3,'EF',20143)
into t1 values(4,'GH',20144)
into t1 values(5,'IJ',20145)
select * from dual;

select * from user_tab_partitions where table_name = 'T1';

select * from t1;

--Creating Partition online
ALTER TABLE t1 
MODIFY PARTITION BY RANGE (yr_qtr) 
INTERVAL (1) ( PARTITION P1 VALUES LESS THAN (20141) ) ONLINE;

select * from t1;

select * from user_tab_partitions where table_name = 'T1';
```

Output:

```
Table dropped.
Table created.
5 row(s) inserted.
no data found
Result Set 5

ID  ACCOUNTNUMBER   YR_QTR
1   AB  20141
2   CD  20142
3   EF  20143
4   GH  20144
5   IJ  20145

Download CSV
5 rows selected.
Table altered.
Result Set 6

ID  ACCOUNTNUMBER   YR_QTR
1   AB  20141
2   CD  20142
3   EF  20143
4   GH  20144
5   IJ  20145

Download CSV
5 rows selected.
Result Set 7

TABLE_NAME  COMPOSITE   PARTITION_NAME  SUBPARTITION_COUNT  HIGH_VALUE  HIGH_VALUE_LENGTH   PARTITION_POSITION  TABLESPACE_NAME PCT_FREE    PCT_USED    INI_TRANS   MAX_TRANS   INITIAL_EXTENT  NEXT_EXTENT MIN_EXTENT  MAX_EXTENT  MAX_SIZE    PCT_INCREASE    FREELISTS   FREELIST_GROUPS LOGGING COMPRESSION COMPRESS_FOR    NUM_ROWS    BLOCKS  EMPTY_BLOCKS    AVG_SPACE   CHAIN_CNT   AVG_ROW_LEN SAMPLE_SIZE LAST_ANALYZED   BUFFER_POOL FLASH_CACHE CELL_FLASH_CACHE    GLOBAL_STATS    USER_STATS  IS_NESTED   PARENT_TABLE_PARTITION  INTERVAL    SEGMENT_CREATED INDEXING    READ_ONLY   INMEMORY    INMEMORY_PRIORITY   INMEMORY_DISTRIBUTE INMEMORY_COMPRESSION    INMEMORY_DUPLICATE  CELLMEMORY  INMEMORY_SERVICE    INMEMORY_SERVICE_NAME
T1  NO  P1  0   20141   5   1   LIVESQL_USERS   10   -  1   255 65536   1048576 1   2147483645  2147483645   -   -   -  YES DISABLED     -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -  DEFAULT DEFAULT DEFAULT NO  NO  NO   -  NO  YES ON  NO  DISABLED     -   -   -   -   -   -   - 
T1  NO  SYS_P29017  0   20142   5   2   LIVESQL_USERS   10   -  1   255 65536   1048576 1   2147483645  2147483645   -   -   -  YES DISABLED     -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -  DEFAULT DEFAULT DEFAULT NO  NO  NO   -  YES YES ON  NO  DISABLED     -   -   -   -   -   -   - 
T1  NO  SYS_P29018  0   20143   5   3   LIVESQL_USERS   10   -  1   255 65536   1048576 1   2147483645  2147483645   -   -   -  YES DISABLED     -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -  DEFAULT DEFAULT DEFAULT NO  NO  NO   -  YES YES ON  NO  DISABLED     -   -   -   -   -   -   - 
T1  NO  SYS_P29019  0   20144   5   4   LIVESQL_USERS   10   -  1   255 65536   1048576 1   2147483645  2147483645   -   -   -  YES DISABLED     -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -  DEFAULT DEFAULT DEFAULT NO  NO  NO   -  YES YES ON  NO  DISABLED     -   -   -   -   -   -   - 
T1  NO  SYS_P29020  0   20145   5   5   LIVESQL_USERS   10   -  1   255 65536   1048576 1   2147483645  2147483645   -   -   -  YES DISABLED     -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -  DEFAULT DEFAULT DEFAULT NO  NO  NO   -  YES YES ON  NO  DISABLED     -   -   -   -   -   -   - 
T1  NO  SYS_P29021  0   20146   5   6   LIVESQL_USERS   10   -  1   255 65536   1048576 1   2147483645  2147483645   -   -   -  YES DISABLED     -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -  DEFAULT DEFAULT DEFAULT NO  NO  NO   -  YES YES ON  NO  DISABLED     -   -   -   -   -   -   - 

Download CSV
6 rows selected.
```

Comment: All commands worked for me up to: `--Creating Partition online
ALTER TABLE t1 
MODIFY PARTITION BY RANGE (yr_qtr) 
INTERVAL (1) ( PARTITION P1 VALUES LESS THAN (20141) ) ONLINE;`
Not sure why.. I am using `Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit`

Comment: can you try partition name as random9801 instead of P1 ? :P

Comment: `Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production 0
PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production 0
CORE 12.2.0.1.0 Production 0
TNS for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production 0
NLSRTL Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production 0`

Comment: `ALTER TABLE t1 
MODIFY PARTITION BY RANGE (yr_qtr) 
INTERVAL (1) ( PARTITION random9802  VALUES LESS THAN (20141) ) ONLINE
Error report -
ORA-14006: invalid partition name
14006. 00000 -  "invalid partition name"
*Cause:    a partition name of the form <identifier> is
           expected but not present.
*Action:   enter an appropriate partition name.`  Does it matter where I am running from? (currently using SQL Developer). Also do you need specific privileges for creating partitions?

Comment: You're using 12c R1

Comment: try with intermediate table and exchange.

Comment: Check this [Ask Tom link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9532333900346891332)

Comment: Do you have example of how to try that?